# Porque no se carga el icono al usar pygame?

Tags: pygame

Estoy trabajando desde pycharm con pygame pero al ejecutar el programa en Ubuntu no se visualiza el icono cargado pero si el mismo código lo ejecuto en pycharm pero en windows si lo visualizo, por que puede pasar esto?

```
#Inicializar pygame
import pygame
import os

pygame.init()

# Crear la pantalla
pantalla = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

# Titulo e Icono
pygame.display.set_caption("Invasion Espacial")

# Cargar el icono
icono = pygame.image.load("ovni2.png")
if icono:
    pygame.display.set_icon(icono)
    print("Tamaño de la imagen:", icono.get_size())
else:
    print("No se pudo cargar la imagen del icono")

# Loop del juego
se_ejecuta = True
while se_ejecuta:
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
        if evento.type == pygame.QUIT:
            se_ejecuta = False
```